# How to scroll to element with Selenium and Node.JS driving Firefox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to scroll to a link element on the page and click it. 
The following solution works for Chrome and IE, but not for Firefox. How could I fix this? Is there any other approach to it?

```
function clickByLinkTextScroll(text){
        driver.findElement(By.linkText(text)).getLocation().then(function (location) {
            driver.executeScript("window.scroll(0," + location.y + ");");
            driver.sleep(300);
            driver.findElement(By.linkText(text)).click();
        });
};
```

When I run it against Firefox I get the following output:

```
UnknownCommandError: GET /session/ad17a19d-782b-4706-b1d7-b56f0139b252/element/5c5e0c3d-1861-432c-b402-b6a010c2f268/location did not match a known command
    at WebDriverError (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at UnknownCommandError (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:296:5)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:477:11)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:388:15)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:330:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebElement.getLocation()
    at Driver.schedule (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:414:17)
    at WebElementPromise.schedule_ (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1823:25)
    at WebElementPromise.getLocation (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:2112:17)
    at clickByLinkTextScroll (innovationCentralTests.js:694:43)
    at Context.&lt;anonymous&gt; (innovationCentralTests.js:445:9)
    at C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\testing\index.js:153:19
    at new ManagedPromise (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1017:7)
    at controlFlowExecute (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\testing\index.js:138:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2731:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2714:21)
    at asyncRun (C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2631:25)
    at C:\ProgramData\npm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
```

Comment: use `scrollIntoView()` method.try the below code `driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",driver.findElement(By.linkText(text)))`

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As  Sudharsan Selvaraj suggested, I used the following and it did the job nicely:

```
function clickByLinkTextScroll(text) {
    element = driver.findElement(By.linkText(text));
    driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element);
    driver.sleep(300);
    element.click();
};
```